# com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer createCollection: Unable to create new Collection instance for type java.util.Arrays$ArrayList

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, collections, selectmanycheckbox

I'm trying to use JSF / SelectManyCheckBox tag with an enum :

Here is my xhtml code :

```
            <h:form id="searchForm">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <h:outputText value="Searched queues" />
                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <h:selectManyCheckbox layout="pageDirection" value="#{jmsErrorController.errorSearchCriteria.searchedQueues}" converter="queueConverter">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{jmsErrorController.completeQueueList}" />
                        </h:selectManyCheckbox>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:commandButton action="#{jmsErrorController.search}"
                    value="Search !" />
            </h:form>
```

I've add a converter as stated in an other post.

It seems to work fine but I see this stack trace on the console :

```
28-Jun-2013 09:07:46 com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer createCollection
SEVERE: Unable to create new Collection instance for type java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
java.lang.InstantiationException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:340)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.createCollection(MenuRenderer.java:907)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectManyValuesForModel(MenuRenderer.java:367)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectManyValue(MenuRenderer.java:129)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.getConvertedValue(MenuRenderer.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1030)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:960)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1233)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:698)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1172)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.doIt(WebAppServletContext.java:3684)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3650)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2268)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2174)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1446)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

After this stacktrace, the application seems to work fine but I wonder why is there such a stacktrace..

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Stéphane.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This will happen when the `UISelectMany` component's `value` being provided is created using [`Arrays#asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) method instead of [`new ArrayList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

If a model `value` is already prepopulated, JSF will try to use exactly the same type to put submitted values in and set the new model value. However, the `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList` type as returned by `Arrays#asList()` is internal to `java.util.Arrays` class and not individually instantiable as in `new Arrays$ArrayList()`. Hence this exception.

To fix this, make sure that the value is created using `new ArrayList()`.

Alternatively, explicitly specify the collection type via `collectionType` attribute as instructed in this closely related answer: [org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectManyValuesForModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245426/org-hibernate-lazyinitializationexception-at-com-sun-faces-renderkit-html-basic/25249537#25249537).

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox ... collectionType="java.util.ArrayList">
```

Comment: One user is facing this issue, while I am not able to replicate on the same running instance. The code clearly has the indicated problem: bean value initialized with `Arrays.asList()`. Only difference with this issue is that am using the primefaces version, with the `p:selectManyCheckbox` inside a `<form>` without submit and read through `<p:ajax>`. Can you describe the exact condition where it tries to re-instantiate the `Arrays$ArrayList` ?

Comment: It also solve `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.ImmutableCollections$ListN.<init>()`