# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectManyValuesForModel

Tags: jsf, jpa, lazy-loading, eager-loading, selectmanymenu

Despite of `FetchType.EAGER` and `JOIN FETCH`, I get a `LazyInitalizationException` while adding some objects to a `@ManyToMany` collection via a JSF `UISelectMany` component such as in my case the `<p:selectManyMenu>`.

The `@Entity IdentUser`, with `FetchType.EAGER`:

```
@Column(name = "EMPLOYERS")
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "USER_COMPANY", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_ID") })
private Set<Company> employers = new HashSet<Company>();
```

The `@Entity Company`, with `FetchType.EAGER`:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="employers", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<IdentUser> employee;
```

The JPQL, with `JOIN FETCH`:

```
public List<IdentUser> getAllUsers() {
    return this.em.createQuery("from IdentUser u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.employers WHERE u.enabled = 1 AND u.accountNonLocked=0 ").getResultList();
}
```

The JSF `UISelectMany` component causing the exception while submitting:

```
<p:selectManyMenu value="#{bean.user.employers}" converter="#{entityConverter}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.companies}" var="company" itemValue="#{company}" itemLabel="#{company.name}"/>
</p:selectManyMenu>
```

The relevant part of the stack trace:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:545)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.add(PersistentSet.java:206)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectManyValuesForModel(MenuRenderer.java:382)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectManyValue(MenuRenderer.java:129)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.getConvertedValue(MenuRenderer.java:315)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectmanymenu.SelectManyMenuRenderer.getConvertedValue(SelectManyMenuRenderer.java:37)
    ...
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

While submitting, the JSF `UISelectMany` components need to create a **brand new** instance of the collection with the submitted and converted values prefilled. It won't clear out and reuse the existing collection in the model as that may either get reflected in other references to the same collection, or may fail with an `UnsupportedOperationException` because the collection is unmodifiable, such as the ones obtained by `Arrays#asList()` or `Collections#unmodifiableList()`.

The [`MenuRenderer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.2.0/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/MenuRenderer.java#MenuRenderer), the renderer behind [`UISelectMany`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UISelectMany.html) (and [`UISelectOne`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UISelectOne.html)) components who's responsible for this all, will by default create a brand new instance of the collection based on collection's `getClass().newInstance()`. This would in turn fail with `LazyInitializationException` if the `getClass()` returns an implementation of Hibernate's [`PersistentCollection`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/collection/spi/PersistentCollection.html) which is internally used by Hibernate to fill the collection property of an entity. The `add()` method namely needs to initialize the underlying proxy via the current session, but there's none because the job isn't performed within a transactional service method.

To override this default behavior of `MenuRenderer`, you need to **explicitly** specify the FQN of the desired collection type via the `collectionType` attribute of the `UISelectMany` component. For a `List` property, you'd like to specify `java.util.ArrayList` and for a `Set` property, you'd like to specify `java.util.LinkedHashSet` (or `java.util.HashSet` if ordering isn't important):

```
<p:selectManyMenu ... collectionType="java.util.LinkedHashSet">
```

The same applies to all other `UISelectMany` components as well which are directly tied to a Hibernate-managed JPA entity. E.g:

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox ... collectionType="java.util.LinkedHashSet">
<h:selectManyCheckbox ... collectionType="java.util.LinkedHashSet">
<h:selectManyListbox ... collectionType="java.util.LinkedHashSet">
<h:selectManyMenu ... collectionType="java.util.LinkedHashSet">
```

See also the [VDL documentation of among others `<h:selectManyMenu>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/selectManyMenu.html). This is unfortunately not specified in [VDL documentation of `<p:selectManyMenu>`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/5.0/core/primefaces-p/selectManyMenu.html), but as they use the same renderer for converting, it must work. If the IDE is jerking about an unknown `collectionType` attribute and annoyingly underlines it even though it works when you ignore'n'run it, then use `<f:attribute>` instead.

```
<p:selectManyMenu ... >
    <f:attribute name="collectionType" value="java.util.LinkedHashSet" />
    ...
</p:selectManyMenu>
```

Comment: @Tomczak Thank you for youre explenation, to get an better understanding of the problem. I've thought it's up to JPA+Hibernate, didn't had JSF in focus. Your provided solution, will work, I'am sure, but this was not my favoured way (using BOs instead of Entities).Here I would prefere "BalusC" solution... Thanks a lot, it works fine for me.

Comment: What is VDL of a.o. ?

Comment: @Koray: I clarified the answer.

Answer (score 6):

**Solution: Replace the `editUserBehavior.currentUser.employers` with collection that is not managed by Hibernate.**

Why? When the Entity becomes managed, the Hibernate replaces your `HashSet` with its own implementation of `Set` (be it `PersistentSet`). By analysing the implementation of JSF `MenuRenderer`, it turns out that at one point it creates new `Set` reflectively. See the comment in `MenuRenderer.convertSelectManyValuesForModel()`

> // try to reflect a no-argument constructor and invoke if available

During construction of `PersistentSet`  `initialize()` is invoked and - as this class is only meant to be invoked from Hibernate - LazyInitializationException is thrown.

Note: This is my suspicion only. I don't know your versions of JSF and Hibernate but this is more likely the case.