# p:selectCheckboxMenu throwing org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException

Tags: hibernate, jpa, primefaces

I'm developing a JSF app using p:selectCheckboxMenu from Primefaces but it is not working because when I try to save an existing record, it throws LazyInitializationException. It happens only to entities being updated, I mean, it works when I save new entity.

Why LazyInitializationException is being thrown if my list attribute in entity is marked as Eager?

Here is the exception:

```
11:19:12,988 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-10) failed to lazily initialize a collection, could not initialize proxy - no Session: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:587)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.write(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:397)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.add(PersistentBag.java:297)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectManyValuesForModel(MenuRenderer.java:381)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectManyValue(MenuRenderer.java:128)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.getConvertedValue(MenuRenderer.java:314)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectcheckboxmenu.SelectCheckboxMenuRenderer.getConvertedValue(SelectCheckboxMenuRenderer.java:44)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1045)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:975)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1248)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at com.bristech.wportal.web.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:387)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "WPR_SEC_COMP")
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = { "componentId" })
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ComponentSecurityConfig implements BaseEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "COMPONENT_ID", length = 64)

    private String componentId;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "WPR_JT_SEC_COMP_ROLE", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "COMPONENT_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "SECURITY_ROLE_NAME") })
    private List<SecurityRole> roles = new ArrayList<SecurityRole>();

    @Column(name = "PERM_GROUP_WRITE")

    private Boolean groupWrite;

    @Column(name = "PERM_OTHER_READ")

    private Boolean otherRead;

    public ComponentSecurityConfig() {

    }

    public String getComponentId() {
        return componentId;
    }

    public void setComponentId(String componentId) {
        this.componentId = componentId;
    }

    public List<SecurityRole> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<SecurityRole> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public Boolean getGroupWrite() {
        return groupWrite;
    }

    public void setGroupWrite(Boolean groupWrite) {
        this.groupWrite = groupWrite;
    }

    public Boolean getOtherRead() {
        return otherRead;
    }

    public void setOtherRead(Boolean otherRead) {
        this.otherRead = otherRead;
    }

}
```

Converter:

```
@Named(value = "securityRoleConverter")
@ApplicationScoped
@FacesConverter(forClass = SecurityRole.class, value = "securityRoleConverter")
public class SecurityRoleConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, String value) {
        if (value != null && !value.isEmpty()) {
            return uiComponent.getAttributes().get(value);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, Object value) {
        if (value instanceof SecurityRole) {
            SecurityRole entity = (SecurityRole) value;
            if (entity != null && entity instanceof SecurityRole && entity.getName() != null) {
                uiComponent.getAttributes().put(entity.getName(), entity);
                return entity.getName();
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Composite that holds p:selectCheckboxMenu:

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="#{cc.attrs.id}" value="#{cc.attrs.value}"
            multiple="true" disabled="#{cc.attrs.disabled}"
            label="#{cc.attrs.label}"
            readonly="#{empty cc.attrs.readOnly ? false : cc.attrs.readOnly}"
            required="#{empty cc.attrs.required ? false : cc.attrs.required}"
            styleClass="#{cc.attrs.styleClass}" filterMatchMode="contains"
            filter="#{empty cc.attrs.filter ? true : cc.attrs.filter}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{cc.attrs.itemList}" var="item"
                itemValue="#{item}" itemLabel="#{item[cc.attrs.itemLabel]}" />
            <f:converter converterId="#{cc.attrs.converter}" />

            <composite:insertChildren />
        </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

This is my persistence.xml (there is no hibernate.cfg.)

```
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="primary" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/PGDB</jta-data-source>
        <jar-file>wportal-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</jar-file>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />

            <!-- Options: validate | update | create | create-drop -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I saw similar question at:

[LazyInitializationException in selectManyCheckbox on @ManyToMany(fetch=LAZY)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30103161/lazyinitializationexception-in-selectmanycheckbox-on-manytomanyfetch-lazy)

But in my case, all attributes are EAGER (changed every single entity in this graph).

When I debugged, I could realize exception is thrown in Converter. Is there anything wrong out there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you passing `ComponentSecurityConfig>roles` to composite composite component as value, Post not showing the component caller also It would be great if you can show the complete stacktrace

Comment: also show us the `persistence.xml` and `hibernate.cfg` files

Comment: No, actually I'm passing just a String ID to managed bean called from composite.

Comment: Ok, just edited my question adding persistence.xml.

Comment: Does it work with a plain comparable jsf component? and are you sure the eager is working?

Comment: It works if I use a simple p:selectOneMenu but it doesn't when I try to use multiple selection component.